# What is the difference between "extended from" and "extending from"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Scenario 1: part A is extended from part B

Scenario 2: part A is extending from part B

Is there any difference between these two descriptions? Would any one so kind to help me about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only difference I see is that in "part A is extended from part B" the act of extending is treated as complete: Part A is in its extended state with respect to part B, and thus need not be in motion. In contrast, in "part A is extending from part B" the act of extending is in process: Like a frog's tongue or a compact telescope being drawn to its full length, part A is moving outward from part B.

Comment: No difference, really. _Extend_ is a verb that has an intransitive use _A extends from B_ and also a causative transitive sense _`Indef` extends A from B_, which -- if you don't know or care about who `Indef` was, you can get rid of it by passivizing it, producing _A is extended from B_. The progressive _is extending_ is the intransitive sense, but it comments on the location; i.e, it implies A was formed from B, is moving from B, or is a subordinate part of B. Either that, or it's an answer for "Where do I find Part A?" I.e, look at part B.

Comment: *Extended* implies (requires) presence of an agent, *extending* does not. They do not mean the same.

Comment: -1 How is this case any different from analogous transitive-intransitive cases? What is special about this?

Answer (score -1):

The question comes to mind whether part A is fixed or movable.  If it can be slid so as to protrude more, or less, or not at all, beyond part B, you could say that it is "being extended" and "being retracted" (or that it "is extending" and "is retracting".)   I don't think I would use "from", unless Part A is completely hidden within Part B when retracted—in which case I would write "Part A is extended from Part B" and "Part A retracts into Part B".     On the other hand, If Part A is fixed, and you are speaking of how far it always protrudes beyond part B, you would simply say "Part A extends [x units] beyond Part B."

Answer (score -1):

I'd give this two aspects: the subject aspect, and the time aspect

For the subject part of my answer 
1; A is elongating from B by effect of a(n unmentioned) subject 
2; A is elongating from B independent of a subject, or if not so, indirectly. The subject could be doing something which in turn makes A to elongate from B

For the time aspect 
1; The time period for A elongating from B is definite 
2; The elongation time seems to be continuous